# How to create multiple object in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am having a `onChange` function i was trying to update the array `optionUpdates` which is inside of `sentdata`  by index wise as i had passed the index to the `onChange` function.

Suppose i update any two values of the input field from `option` which is inside of `postdata` therefore the input name i.e. `orderStatus` with changed value and with `order` should be saved inside of `optionUpdates`

For example: Suppose i update  the option 1 and option 3 of my `postdata` further inside of `options` of `orderStatus` values so my `optionUpdates` which is inside of `sentdata` should look like this

```
optionUpdates: [
{
  Order: 1,
  orderStatus: "NEW1"
},
{
  Order: 3,
  orderStatus: "New2"
}
]
```

here is what i tried

```
setSentData(oldValue => {
      const curoptions = oldValue.sentdata.optionUpdates[idx];
      console.log(curoptions);
      curoptions.event.target.name = event.target.value;
      return {
        ...oldValue,
        sentdata: {
          ...oldValue.sentdata.optionUpdates,
          curoptions
        }
      };
    });
  };
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-thompson-26vvs?file=/src/App.js)

complete code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const x = {
    LEVEL: {
      Type: "LINEN",
      options: [
        {
          Order: 1,
          orderStatus: "INFO",
          orderValue: "5"
        },
        {
          Order: 2,
          orderStatus: "INPROGRESS",
          orderValue: "5"
        },
        {
          Order: 3,
          orderStatus: "ACTIVE",
          orderValue: "9"
        }
      ],
      details: "2020  N/w UA",
      OrderType: "Axes"
    },
    State: "Inprogress"
  };

  const [postdata, setPostData] = React.useState(x);

  const posting = {
    optionUpdates: []
  };

  const [sentdata, setSentData] = React.useState(posting);

  const handleOptionInputChange = (event, idx) => {
    const target = event.target;
    setPostData(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      LEVEL: {
        ...prev.LEVEL,
        options: prev.LEVEL.options.map((item, id) => {
          if (id === idx) {
            return { ...item, [target.name]: target.value };
          }
          return item;
        })
      }
    }));
    setSentData(oldValue => {
      const curoptions = oldValue.sentdata.optionUpdates[idx];
      console.log(curoptions);
      curoptions.event.target.name = event.target.value;
      return {
        ...oldValue,
        sentdata: {
          ...oldValue.sentdata.optionUpdates,
          curoptions
        }
      };
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {postdata.LEVEL.options.map((item, idx) => {
        return (
          <input
            key={idx}
            type="text"
            name="orderStatus"
            value={postdata.LEVEL.options[idx].orderStatus}
            onChange={e => handleOptionInputChange(e, idx)}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly then what you're looking to do is save a copy of the relevant options object in `sentdata` every time one changes. I think the best way to approach this is by doing all your state modification outside of `setPostData`, which then makes the results immediately available to both `setPostData` and `setSentData`. It will also make the setters easier to read, which is good because you have some quite deeply nested and complicated state here.

A few other things worth noting first:

1. Trying to use synchronous event results directly inside the asynchronous setter functions will throw warnings. If you do need to use them inside setters, then it is best to destructure them from the event object first. This implementation uses destructuring although it didn't end up being necessary in the end.
2. You seem to have got a bit muddled up with `setSentData`. The `oldValue` parameter returns the whole state, as `prev` in `setPostData` does. For `oldValue.sentdata` you just wanted `oldValue`. You also wanted `curoptions[event.target.name]`, not `curoptions.event.target.name`.

So, on to your code. I would suggest that you change the way that your input is rendered so that you are using a stable value rather than just the index. This makes it possible to reference the object no matter which array it is in. I have rewritten it using the `Order` property - if this value is not stable then you should assign it one. Ideally you would use a long `uuid`.

```
    {postdata.LEVEL.options.map(item => {
        return (
          <input
            key={item.Order}
            type="text"
            name="orderStatus"
            value={item.orderStatus}
            onChange={e => handleOptionInputChange(e, item.Order)}
          />
        );
    })}
```

The `handleOptionInputChange` function will now use this `Order` property to find the correct objects in both `postdata` and `sentdata` and update them, or if it does not exist in `sentdata` then push it there. You would do this by cloning, modifying, and returning the relevant array each time, as I explained before. Here is the function again with comments:

```
    const handleOptionInputChange = (event, orderNum) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;

        /* Clone the options array and all objects 
        inside so we can mutate them without 
        modifying the state object */
        const optionsClone = postdata.LEVEL.options
          .slice()
          .map(obj => Object.assign({}, obj));

        /* Find index of the changed object */
        const optionIdx = optionsClone.findIndex(obj => obj.Order === orderNum);

        /* If the orderNum points to an existing object...*/
        if (optionIdx >= 0) {

          /* Change the value of object in clone */
          optionsClone[optionIdx][name] = value;

          /* Set postdata with the modified optionsClone */
          setPostData(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            LEVEL: {
              ...prev.LEVEL,
              options: optionsClone
            }
          }));

          /* Clone the optionUpates array and all 
          contained objects from sentdata */
          const updatesClone = sentdata.optionUpdates
            .slice()
            .map(obj => Object.assign({}, obj));

          /* Find the index of the changed object */
          const updateIdx = updatesClone.findIndex(obj => obj.Order === orderNum);

          /* If the changed object has already been 
          changed before, alter it again, otherwise push 
          a new object onto the stack*/
          if (updateIdx >= 0) {
            updatesClone[updateIdx][name] = value;
          } else {
            updatesClone.push({ Order: orderNum, [name]: value });
          }

          /* Set sentdata with modified updatesClone */
          setSentData(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            optionUpdates: updatesClone
          }));
        }
    };
```

Comment: Hi @lawrence-witt. There seems a small problem that is whenever i update the value for the input field it does create the new object each time , where as it should update in same object in ```sentdata``` . even on single update ```setSentData``` it create new object

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought that's what you wanted. I do wonder why sentdata is even necessary now though, since its just a copy of `x.LEVEL.options`? The solution is basically to do the same thing again; clone the array of objects you want to modify, mutate it, then put it back into state. I've updated my answer using the `Order` property to do this, although I don't know if it's a stable value. If it's not then you should assign each option a unique identifier to use in place of `idx`.

Comment: Hi @lawrence-witt Can you please bring some comment in the code as i am getting confused in some points, if possible.

Comment: Can you tell how does my optionsClone get update with name and value as you have never updated that one

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you're after now and have done a rewrite of my answer. We update optionsClone when we update `alteredObject`, as it retains its reference to `optionsClone`. This is why we had to clone everything in the first place, to stop the original state being mutated by reference. EDIT: I realised we don't need `alteredObject` at all anymore, it's gone now and we target `optionsClone` directly.

Comment: ok great  now i get it Thankyou so much. You just have a greater mind and great logic. Do give some suggestion to me too, so that i can apply the same logic.